# How get a constant value into anonymous type in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm tring to create a methode to response to this case:

```
this.GetRessource<T>(p => new { expression = "TestConstant", p.Property });
```

The GetRessource methode must extract the constant value and the property name. I found how to extract the property name, but I not find how to get the constant value.

There is my methode.

```
public void GetResource<TObject>(Expression<Func<TObject, object>> expression)
{
    string constantValue = string.Empty;
    string propertyName = string.Empty;

    // Get propertyName.
    var expressionProperties = expression.Body.Type.GetProperties();
    var properties = typeof (TObject).GetProperties()
                                          .Where(pO => lExpressionProperties.Any(pE => pO.Name == pE.Name))
                                          .Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();

     propertyName = lProperties[0]; // = Property
     // constantValue = ?? ;  // must return TestConstant

}
```

I call it like that

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p");
var constantExpression = Expression.Constant(this.Id, typeof(string));
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, object>>(constantExpression, parameterExpression).Compile();
this.GetRessource<T>(p => new { expression, p.Property });
```

Someone had already be in this situation? Is it possible ? Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: `new { "TestConstant", p.Property }` isn't valid C# code to start with, regardless of your implementation and completely aside from lambda expressions. You should work out the calling side first, *then* you can implement it.

Comment: Are you able to specify the type of the object when you are initializing it rather than using an anonymous type?

Comment: @JonSkeet isn't this valid code in the sense that it complies, he is simply creating an anonymous object no?

Comment: @user2202911: No, it doesn't compile. You can only specify a value (without a property name) in an anonymous type instance creation expression when that value is extracted via some member, at which point the member name is used as the property name. Here we've just got a string literal.

Comment: I updated my question. Yes, I can specify my object type when I call it.

Comment: Okay, so can't you just get the value of the `expression` property? Is it *always* called `expression`? What is `pE.Name`, and where does that come from? Do you really need this to be an anonymous type at all? (If the property names are always `expression` and `Property`, and the types are always `string` and `object`, why not just create a named type?)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your interest.

My methode is used in 3 case.

   // CASE 1 . Need extract the property name
   this.GetRessource<T>(p => p.Property });    
   // CASE 2 . Need extract the constant Value
   this.GetRessource<T>(p => "Constant" });    
   // CASE 3.  Need extract the constant value and property Name
   this.GetRessource<T>(p => new { expression = "Constant", p.Property });    

My process work for case 1 and 2. I use nodeType of body expression to identify the case. I don't know if is it the better way to do this. I inspirated on GroupBy linq methode.

Comment: Please put all of this information into the question, appropriatly formatted. It would also help if you'd explain the bigger context - *why* are you trying to do any of this? Do you definitely need expression trees at all? Is this meant to interoperate with bits of LINQ?